# BackendConfig with multiple securityPolicys not working

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-armor

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cloud-armor-backendconfig

I have only seen example assigning one securityPolicy but I want to assign multiple ones.

I created the following backend config with 2 policies and applied to my service with `beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: my-backend-config`

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  namespace: cloud-armor-how-to
  name: my-backend-config
spec:
  securityPolicy:
    name: "policy-one"
    name: "policy-two"
```

When I deploy only "policy-two" is applied. Can I assign two policies somehow? I see no docs for this

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the docs that says that you can specify more than one policy. Even the spec says *securityPolicy* the singular and the YAML structure is not an array.

Furthermore, if you look at your spec:

```
spec:
  securityPolicy:
    name: "policy-one"
    name: "policy-two"
```

The YAML standard completely ignores the first `name: "policy-one"` which explains why only `name: "policy-two"` is used.  You can check it on [YAMLlint](http://www.yamllint.com/). To have one more value on your YAML you would have to convert `securityPolicy` to an array. Something like this:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  namespace: cloud-armor-how-to
  name: my-backend-config
spec:
  securityPolicy:
  - name: "policy-one"
  - name: "policy-two"
```

The issue with this is that it's probably not supported by GCP.

Answer (score 0):

This same behavior happens to the regular HTTP(S) Load Balancers. It looks like it's only possible to add only a single Security Policy per target and the same behavior affects the HTTP(S) load Balancers created by the GKE ingress.

[image: ReplacePolicy-message]

It's possible to add more rules for that only security policy. The new rules can be added in the same way as the [first rule](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cloud-armor-backendconfig#creating_a_security_policy_and_rule) was added; however, the priorities of these rules must be different like in the example below:

```
~$ gcloud beta compute security-policies rules create 1000 \
--security-policy ca-how-to-security-policy \
--src-ip-ranges "192.0.2.0/24" \
--action "deny-404"

~$ gcloud beta compute security-policies rules create 1001 \
--security-policy ca-how-to-security-policy \
--src-ip-ranges "11.16.0.0/24" \
--action "deny-404"
```